# Tweepy Cursor and Search API to save all tweets

Tags: python, twitter, cursor, tweepy, rate-limiting

Disclaimer: new to python and Twitter API

I am using tweepy to access the Search API with various filter combinations.  I am iterating over each tweet returned,  processing the tweet and then writing the results to a CSV as a row.

Relevant portion of script:

```
tweets=tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=keywords).items()    

for tweet in tweets:    
*some code*
```

I have not included a max value in .items() because I want to retrieve all available tweets with the keyword (I know this is limited to ~1week in the past).  My keyword returns upwards of 10000 results.  This results in a rate limit exceeded 88 error.

If I include a time.sleep for 15 minutes in my loop and make the request again, I retrieve the same tweets over again.  How can I either retrieve only new results or process all the results without exceeding the rate limit?

Comment: Could you put a filter on a twitter stream? This example filters by geography: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/alexwoolford/streamingNearbyTweets/blob/master/streamingNearbyTweets.ipynb). I know that's not exactly what you're looking for, but I thought you might be able to tweak it for your keyword.

Comment: Yes, you can filter the twitter stream by keyword.  I have a couple of scripts for stream filters in use already.  However, the track parameter on streaming requests can only be set to filter by keyword or location, not both.  See: https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters